# How to change my url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url

http://example.com/profile.php?u=78
I wanted to changed it to be like this

http://example.com/78/
How would I do that?
Please Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to rewrite `http://example.com/78/` to `http://example.com/profile.php?u=78`, right? Won't rewriting it the other way from `http://example.com/profile.php?u=78` to `http://example.com/78/` end up with a HTTP 404?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.htaccess` in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ /profile.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^u=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ /%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302,L]` to `[R=301,L]` when that work well

Comment: `http://example.com/78/` page does not need to exist because it is redirected to `http://example.com/profile.php?u=78` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to rewrite `http://example.com/profile.php?u=78` into `http://example.com/78/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ /%2/
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]
```

Line-by-line explanation:

1. Turn on rewriting functionality
2. Specify the condition to make sure the query string is in the form of `foo=bar` for the following rules to apply.
3. Rewrite `profile.php?foo=bar` into `/bar/?foo=bar`
4. Remove all query strings that may still be appended to the new URL like `/bar/?foo=bar/`. This rule essentially substitute the entire path (.*) with itself ($1), and emptying the query string (?). `[R=permanent]` performs a permanent redirect (301).

Also, as previously commented, please ensure that `http://example.com/78/` is a valid URL.